# Remove rubocop comments from Yardoc documentation

Tags: ruby, rubocop, yardoc

We are using Yardoc to create the HTML documentation for a number of gems and my company's apps. We are also using Rubocop to for style guide compliance.

The issue I am running into is that we have to enable/disable some of the method metrics and those comments (`# rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize`, etc...) showing up in our documentation. Is there a plugin that removes these or some guide I can follow on creating my own?

Comment: If I understand it right, you want to disable these metrics only for certain methods. you can try to pull out those methods into a separate module/file and then ignore that file through the .rubocop.yml file. That way you don't need to have the # rubocop:disable comment in the code.

Comment: The methods should probably remain where they are. I think it would weird to pull out a single method just to satisfy rubocop.

Comment: Assuming you are putting the # rubocop:disable before documentation comments of a method, can you try inserting an extra newline after this line? does that fix your issue?

Comment: @sxm1972 That did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Great. Please mark my answer as the correct answer in that case. It would help to close out this question as well as help others with a documented answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable rubocop directives in the code from appearing in YARDOC documentation insert a newline after the comment. e.g.

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize

# Converts the object into textual markup given a specific format.
#
# @param format [Symbol] the format type, `:text` or `:html`
# @return [String] the object converted into the expected format.
def to_format(format = :html)
  # format the object
end
```